# Botão de Clipboard - Copiar para Área de Transferência

Tags: novo-recurso

Em alguns sites que tem um bloco de código tem um botão de **Copy to Clipboard** no canto direito, esquerdo, superior ou inferior.

As vezes o usuário posta uma pergunta com um bloco de código, principalmente HTML, CSS e JS, que eu quero testar. Então eu vou num JSFiddle ou CodePen e copio e colo.

Mas seria útil ter o botão para reduzir esse processo, ou até mesmo para copiar o código na resposta.

Sei que no ambiente de teste do StackOverflow tem o botão "Copiar para uma nova resposta" para a resposta, **mas não para área de transferência**. Mas só no ambiente, como na imagem abaixo não tem.

[Pergunta de Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168003/como-customizar-as-setas-do-simple-paginator/172554#172554)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Site de Exemplo do Botão](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: Estou tentando encontrar um exemplo disso, embora a maioria sabe do que eu estou falando.

Comment: Também sinto falta de uma funcionalidade dessa, ainda mais quando preciso rodar algo no CodePen ou outro fiddle.

Comment: Tem coisas que não são reproduzíveis.

Comment: wow, tem botão agora. nice :)

Comment: Onde tem o botão que eu não vi?