# Colar Imagem da Área de Transferência com [Ctrl | Command] + V, é possível?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto

[Eu sei que já tem essa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5594/bot%c3%a3o-de-clipboard-copiar-para-%c3%81rea-de-transfer%c3%aancia), mas queria algo mais específico. No Ghost ou no GitHub, quando quero colocar uma imagem que copiei de algum lugar, faço com <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> e existe um JS que sobe a imagem pra algum lugar e coloca o link formatado.

É bem pouco prático ter que salvar a imagem ou abrir um editor de imagem, colar, salvar, pra daí mandar a imagem pra cá.

Comment: Essa é uma das coisas que mais desejo de melhoria, incluindo no chat.

Comment: Relacionado, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173448/155051;

Answer (score 5):

## Você tentou colar na modal de Imagem?

[image: Imagem - Ctrl+V]